# Передать в функцию переменную из самой функции.

Tags: php, функции

```
$b = "как вывести: ". $a ."?";
function test($a) {
    global $b;
    echo "Подскажите, $b"; 
}
test("test"); // Подскажите, как вывести: ?


$b = " вывести: ";
$c = " только так?";
function test2($a) {
    global $b, $c;
    echo "Или можно, ". $b . $a . $c; 
}
test2("test"); // Или можно, вывести: test только так?
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял, что вы хотите

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я думал на примере поймете, если посмотреть первую функцию хочу что бы вывело "Подскажите, как вывести: test?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php)

```
$pattern = "как вывести: {placeholder}?";
function test($a) {
    global $pattern;
    echo "Подскажите, ".str_replace("{placeholder}",$a, $pattern); 
}
test("test"); // Подскажите, как вывести: test?
```

Comment: Гениально! Спасибо, я бы не додумался :)